# Cannot change UI from the thread in winform

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, user-interface

I'm doing some tasks about multithread. First, I create form 1 that will connect to server with socket: `clientSocket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8888);` , 
then I create a thread call getMessage which will listen to message from server: 
`ctThread = new Thread(getMessage);  ctThread.Start();`  
and the getMessage function here:

```
while (true)
            {
                serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
                int buffSize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
                serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize);
                string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
                readData = "" + returndata;
                if (readData.IndexOf("$") != -1)
                {
                    readData = readData.Substring(0, readData.IndexOf("$"));
                    newFrm = new Form1();
                    newFrm.doNetworkMethod(readData);
                }
            }
```

then I create doNetworkMethod in Form2 for Form1 to send data to Form2, and in form2 in Load Event Function I have
`doNetworkDelegate w = doNetworkMethod; 
w.BeginInvoke(readData, null, null);`

Before that, I created 2 delegate 
`public delegate void doNetworkDelegate(string readData);
public delegate void displayChatDelegate(string readData);`

and finally, I created 2 function call:

```
public void doNetworkMethod(string readData)
    {
        if (readData != null)
        {
            if (!this.IsHandleCreated) this.CreateHandle();
            this.Invoke(new displayChatDelegate(displayChatMethod), new object[] { readData.ToString() });
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }
    public void displayChatMethod(string readData)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + readData;
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + readData; 
        }
    }
```

but `textBox1` and `textBox2` not show readData content but when I created `MessageBox.show(readData)` it does.
Thanks for your helps

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create UI elements in a non-UI thread.

Your code `newFrm = new Form1();` being called in the `getMessage` function needs to be marshalled back to the UI thread before being called.